# How to pass a string literal to a function with explicit section storage

Tags: c, microcontroller, string-literals, sections

Please forgive if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find a question like it.

The problem is like this: for a certain microcontroller I need selected string literals to be in another section than the default .rodata section. The "other" section will be put in flash (which can only be read 4 bytes at a time, so it can't be used freely, the function needs to be aware of the fact), while the .rodata section gets copied into ram, which is useful, because ram can be read without alignment restrictions, but it is very limited in size.

The construction I now use is like this:

```
#define roflash __attribute__((section(".flash.rodata"))) __attribute__((aligned(sizeof(char*))))  

static roflash const char literal[] = "text";
```

(+ modifications in the loader script of course).

This works as intended. But it means for every string handling function I'm calling something like this:

```
static roflash const char literal[] = "text";
do_something(literal);
```

The holy grail would be something that can combine both into one "black box" construction, so I can write `do_something_roflash("text")`;

I guess it would be something with a #define and a code block, so the same variable name could be used over and over again. But then I get stuck, because some of the functions have a variable number of arguments, so something like this won't work:

```
#define function_roflash(s) { \
static roflash const char str[] = s; \
function_roflash_implementation(s); \
}
```

In fact I guess I'd need a variable-argument #define, does that exist?

Other solutions also very welcome.

Thx.

Comment: Yes, "gcc variadic macros" exist. Just copy that into your favorite search engine.

Comment: Hey, this already seems to be the best solution, never thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: If using C11, consider using `_Generic`.

Answer (score 0):

One idea for a somewhat generic GCC variadic macro is:

```
#define roflash(func, str, ...) { \
    static roflash const char s[] = str; \
    func(s, __VA_ARGS__); \
}
```

With just one macro you could support many functions that accept one string constant as the first parameter:

```
roflash(printf, "%d", 42);
roflash(do_something, "text");
roflash(obj.write, "text");
roflash(obj->write, "text");
```